# Php daily, weekly, mounthly registered user count

Tags: php

I need help about php count query for registered user daily, weekly and mounthly. So totaly registered user is easy but my mined is confused for daily,weekly and mounthly registered user count. Anyone can tell me how can i do that ?

I have tryed the following code for daily but it didn't work, not have any error or warning.

```
public function UserDaily(){
  $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * 
  FROM users 
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(registered) > CURRENT_DATE 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(registered) < (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY )")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count today.

```
public function UserDaily(){
  $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"select count(*) as count_today
  from users
  where datetime >= curdate();
  ")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));    
}
```

Count Week.

```
public function UserWeek(){
  $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"select count(*) as count_today
  from users
  where yearweek(datetime) = yearweek(curdate());
  ")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));    
}
```

Count month.

```
public function UserMonth(){
  $query = mysqli_query($this->db,"select count(*) as count_today
  from users
  where and year(datetime) = year(curdate())
       and month(datetime) = month(curdate());
  ")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));    
}
```

Pls have a look at this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: you dont need the FROM_UNIXTIME in your query, registered field is already a unix timestamp that datetime can work with without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1.Daily report

```
SELECT * CONCAT(datetime) AS week

             FROM users

                WHERE

            GROUP BY date(datetime)

            ORDER BY date(datetime) DESC

            LIMIT 0,2000
```

2.Weekly Report;

```
SELECT DISTINCT WEEK( datetime)

            FROM users

                   WHERE GROUP BY WEEK(datetime)

            ORDER BY WEEK(datetime) LIMIT 0 , 2000";
```

3.Monthly report

```
SELECT  MONTHNAME(datetime) AS

MONTH

FROM users

WHERE

GROUP BY MONTHNAME( datetime)

ORDER BY MONTHNAME( datetime)

LIMIT 0 , 2000";
```